# jQuery submit form via submit button

Tags: php, jquery

Is it possible to submit a form by clicking a div-element as if it was submitted by the submit button?

So that this PHP works:

`if(isset($_POST["share"])) { /* do something*/ }`

Form:

```
<form id="form" action="publish.php" method="POST">

  <textarea name="description" maxlength="500">Description...</textarea>

  <input type="submit" name="share" value="Share" />

</form>
```

This does NOT post the share value, $_POST['share'].

```
if($(".post-form").length){

        $(".post-form").click(function(event) {

            $("#form").submit();
            return false;

        });

    }
```

Comment: Take a look at jquery `submit()` method. http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: read the comments below. that does not help

Comment: `share` is an `input` with `type = "submit"`. What do you want to get from there? That's why `$_POST['share']` isn't set, I guess. You probably want to get `$_POST['description']` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible by using the `.submit()` function. You can use it like so:

```
// Wait until the document has been fully loaded
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Bind a click event to your element
    $('div').click(function(event) {

        // Submit the form
        // The callback should add a hidden field with the name "share"
        $('form').submit(function(eventObj) {
            $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
                .attr('name', "share")
                .attr('value', "Share")
                .appendTo('form');
            return true;
        });
    });
});
```

You can find more information [here](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hdLvmdn7/2/)

Comment: Hi, that does post the form but doesn't send a value via $_POST['share'] so the function if(isset($_POST["share"])) { /* do something*/ } does not work.

Comment: @Joseph Your form must have a method="post" attribute

Comment: it does, I updated the question, do you understand the problem now?

Comment: @Joseph try changing your submit button to a "hidden" type, or add it as a text field, optionally just check if $_POST['description'] is set instead, as the $_POST['submit'] doesn't really do anything useful ;)

Comment: I know there are solutions but the question is if there is a way to trigger the submit-button click by clicking on a div instead with jQuery. The submit-button should be there still in case js is disabled.

Comment: @Joseph You could achieve this using a callback to add an extra form field just before submit, this will cause the "share" parameter to be sent with your request. (see my updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

Set an id for submit button:

```
  <input type="submit" name="share" value="Share" id="btn_submit" />
```

then you can control it in jquery like this:

```
$("#btn_submit").onclick(function(){
    if(condition==true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
});
```